# Is this possible to dynamically to generate an attribute in a python object?

Tags: python, object, dynamic, python-3.x

For example, the object only have two attributes, person object, in this example, 
only have first name, and second name. 
Is this possible to make a gender attribute on the fly? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

short answer: yes

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = 'Will'
        self.second_name = 'Awesome'

my_guy = Person()
my_guy.gender = "Male"
print(my_guy.gender)
```

will print `Male`

Comment: Care should be taken with this approach: If you call `Person().gender`, you'd get an AttributeError, so make sure to catch it if it's possible the attr isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

In case you even know what this attribute is called when you write code, you can

```
my_guy = Person()

attr = 'secret_habit'  # this could be read from file, keybrd etc.
value = 'wont tell you'
setattr( my_guy, attr, value)

print(my_guy.secret_habit)
```

i get 'wont tell you'

Comment: Forget about `__dict__` and use `setattr`/`getattr`. Accessing the instance dictionary is fragil, it fails in a number of cases (e.g. `__slots__`, old-style classes, properties, other attribute access overriding, possibly even more) that may not be the majority, but definitely common enough to consider.

Comment: @delan:  fixed it as you suggested.